# Error Configuration DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

What may be my problem, it's seems My Dnn doesn't want to load DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config

> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.GetDecryptionkey()
>   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Host.Host.get_SMTPPassword() at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Host.HostSettings.BindSmtpServer() at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Host.HostSettings.BindData() at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Host.HostSettings.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database with another application such as sql management studio? Seems like it's telling you it can't connect. Have you made any changes recently? Have you built a module in VS recently or created a new module project? If so you can check IIS and see if your sites folder structure contains and virtual directories or applications. If so delete those.

Comment: The site and the database is working fine, 
I've this error when I try to access, from the site to the page sistem setting

Comment: thx you for helped me, a workmate came and told me what was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machineKey section in web.config is missing.

http://dotnetnukeru.com/Dnn6Docs/api/html/T_DotNetNuke_Common_Utilities_Config.htm

> Returns the decryptionkey from webconfig machinekey